# are google chrome extensions, open source or not?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm editing some extensions source codes, to create better or other extentions, some have a license file to tell you what you can do but many do not have, all i can see is a comment saying: all rights reserved by example.com so can i modify these extensions or not?

Comment: Which part of "all rights reserved" is difficult to understand? :) If you replaced "Chrome extensions" with "Chrome", or "OS X", or "the CPU in my computer", would it make any difference?

Comment: @bzlm Chrome Extensions are built by third parties and have many different license agreements. There is no explicit "All rights reserved" default for them.

Comment: @Chuck, not talking about any defaults, simply referring to the ones that have "a comment saying: all rights reserved by example.com" in them. But I'm guessing there *is* a default set of rights reserved for any reasonably trademarkable intellectual property as well. This is certainly true in the offline world. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chrome extension source code can be viewed but it can still be under a copyright license. Need to ask the extension owner about the license details.

Comment: Note that an extension's presence on the Chrome Web Store requires that the developer "grant to the user a non-exclusive, worldwide, and perpetual license to perform, display, and use the Products and any content contained in, accessed by, or transmitted through the Products in connection with Google Chrome." (According to https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/terms) Any license terms beyond that are at the developer's discression.

Answer (score 12):

Every Chrome Extension gives the user the following rights by default:

> 5.2 You grant to the user a non-exclusive, worldwide, and perpetual license to perform, display, and use the Products and any content
>   contained in, accessed by, or transmitted through the Products in
>   connection with Google Chrome. If you choose, you may include a
>   separate end user license agreement (EULA) in your Product that will
>   govern the user’s rights to the Products in lieu of the previous
>   sentence.

Read the whole agreement here: http://developer.chrome.com/webstore/terms

Beyond that you will need to speak to the developer in question. Annoyingly the Google store does not display license terms for each Extension by default.

Comment: Note that this only applies if the extension was distributed through the web store.